# How to Upgrade to 12.10 Safely?

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

So I going to upgrade but, I don't want to break my computer again so how do I upgrade safely?

Comment: Do you have a specific concern? The question is too broad right now.

Comment: My Question has been answered(Scroll Down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too hard actually.

1. Open your Updates Manager;
2. Click 'Settings' in bottom left;
3. In the new window, select the 'Updates' tab;
4. Under 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' select 'For any new version';
5. Make sure you don't change any other setting;
6. Run the updater and you will be prompted to upgrade to the newest version, 12.10 that is.

Things to remember:

- Make sure to back up your important documents, just in case;
- If you have any custom PPAs added, make sure to re-enable them after the upgrade;
- Although 12.10 is a stable release, it's the 12.04 that is a LTS; So it's the 12.04 that is recommended for usage on production machines.

Source: [OMG! Ubuntu! "[How To] Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Thank you for Replying! I message back if things go well!

Comment: Please message back even if things do not go well ;)

Comment: @Tomnua OK then I will

Comment: It worked! YAY!

Comment: There you go I accepted it but, now the unity thing won't show

Comment: Try searching around this website, I've seen people asking questions about that problem.

Comment: I reinstalled so now I good